# How do I declare embedded css with Binding.scala

Tags: css, syntax-error, scala.js, scala-xml, binding.scala

I tried to declare some embedded css with Binding.scala

```
import com.thoughtworks.binding._, Binding._
import org.scalajs.dom._

@dom def css = <style>
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
</style>

dom.render(document.head, css)
```

However, I got the error message:

```
ScalaFiddle.scala:6: error: not found: type lightblue
      background-color: lightblue;
                        ^
ScalaFiddle.scala:6: error: not found: value background
      background-color: lightblue;
      ^
ScalaFiddle.scala:6: error: not found: value color
      background-color: lightblue;
                 ^
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see the error message because `{` is a special character in Scala's XML literal.

Use a `CDATA` section in the `style` element.

```
@dom def css = <style>
  <![CDATA[
    body {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
  ]]>
</style>
```

The `{` does not have special meaning in the `CDATA` section any more.

---

Note this `CDATA` approach only works when `coalescing` flag is on.
See https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala/issues/30 and https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala/issues/58 if you accidentally turns the flag off.

Comment: This question and answer is moved from https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer of Yang Bo:

```
@dom def css = <style>
  <![CDATA[
    body {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
  ]]>
</style>
```

Gives me an Exception:

```
ScalaFiddle.scala:22: error: overloaded method value domBindingSeq with alternatives:
  ( text: String)binding.this.Binding.Constants[raw.this.Text] 
...
```

See https://scalafiddle.io/sf/ATMVpjV/0

This solved it:

```
  @dom def css = <style>
  {"""
    body {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
    """
  }
</style>
```

See https://scalafiddle.io/sf/ATMVpjV/1

Comment: It seems that ScalaFiddle turned off `coalescing` flag. See https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala/issues/30 and https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala/issues/58